# Phase-space diagrams of microstates-infinite-dimensional?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I've just begun learning Statistical Mechanics and my question concerns my professor's statement and I quote:

> Consider a gas of $N$ atoms which can have position $q_i$ and momentum $p_i$. It is in a volume $V$ and has energy $E$. To get an exact picture of the state a system is in, we have to define all the positions $q_i$ and momenta $p_i$ for all the particles in the system $i = 1, 2, 3, ..., N$. This is an infinite-dimensional space because the variables qi and pi
> can vary continuously.

Why is it infinite dimensional? I would think it is 6-dimensional because all we need to describe a particle would be the position coordinates, and the momenta along the $x,y,z$ directions. I don't grasp this statement at all. Please help.

Comment: Is this from a reference? Which page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes in a lecture, it may happen to make careless mistakes. I would advise everybody to check in the textbook, and if this doesn't provide an answer, ask the lecturer directly.

In the present case, it is clearly false that the space of microstates for a finite system is infinite-dimensional. However, it is not 6-dimensional either. It is $6N$-dimensional.